# nginx upstream is for http but which one is for mail?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

For nginx upstream is used to specify a local server as destination for the http section. Is there a similar one for the mail{} section as I am trying to set up nginx as smtps forwarder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please take a look at this.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_core_module.html

For plus refer
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/

Comment: this link: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/ seems to be out of date. I get an error for the "ssl on" command saying it is deprecated.